# Error 500, not on local but on server

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made this page and it loads normally while on local development but when I try to access it on the server I have an Error 500, can somebody help me ?

I have erased my .htaccess, looked in the log and I have nothing really interesting

```html
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Actus
*
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
*
*/

get_header('other'); ?>

<section id ="page-title" class="col-md-12">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <header class="row extra-bottom-padding">
        <div class="section_title col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12 top-buffer">
          <h1 class="title">Actus</h1>
          <hr class="divider_blue">
        </div>

      </header>
      <?

      $args = array("posts_per_page" => "12", "category_name" => "actus, cest-fait");
      $the_query = new WP_Query ($args);
      $x = 1;
      foreach ($args as $arg)
      if($x % 4 == 0) echo '<div class="row">';
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="le_post_entier">
          <? the_post_thumbnail('actus'); ?>
          <div class="col-md-12 postbody">
            <div class="col-md-12 post-title">
                <? the_title(); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="cta" href="#" style='color:#39c8d8; font-weight:bold;'>DÉCOUVRIR &#8594;</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <?php
    endwhile; ?><?
    $x++;

    if($x % 4 == 0) echo '</div>';
    ?>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please check file permissions as well as user of the file in your FTP Client

Comment: check error log on server

Answer (score 1):

Please check module `mod_rewrite.so` is enabled in your apache configuration.

Open httpd.conf generally located in Apache installation directory in windows

/apache/conf/httpd.conf

and

/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Search for the module `mod_rewrite.so` or (mod_rewrite.c in rare cases).

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.*
```

Here # character represents that it is commented or disabled.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.*
```

Remove # and restart the Apache Http Server

Also check your apache error logs for possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .htaccess file on server.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I have the exact same file :(

Comment: enable **wp_debug** to **true** to check the error in **wp-config** file

Comment: I have tried but it still show error 500. I tried with an other browser

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... I want to cry but the error was amazingly simple

I needed to add

**php** after of `<?`

Hope this will help someone

Comment: It is best practice to use <?php instead of <?. If you want to use short tag <? then you have to enable `short_open_tag` using php.ini configuration file .